# Puzzling.SE top 10 Wordsearch!

Tags: word, visual, word-search

Welcome to the Puzzling.SE top 10 word search, lets get solving:

```
CZSMOCSYLAYOLNTIMMSJZGK 
ZPDAWZMROKTESEWORDUZBLG 
ZFMTNNFZGTJLIGEKPDENRDO
WUJHRFYMIENZDDJRQSKYXIZ 
WMHEEDFCCMLZFETSXXGHANJ
FXUMTJRKAFBUCLMRQLSMUKQ 
GWFATMJELUBPZWEINNKKYVR 
NCBTAZSNDULCBOLJDQFMAFM 
KXXIPKSEEKRIRNDGJEXELIK
TXACDQCMDWTTAKDZUMXNPUQ 
YRNSTZZRUZZANNITHYFNDMQ 
AEYCHDDVCBXMPPRMZHSARLN 
DHELMHHOTQLGSONBHRDPOSH 
PPCOWBLZILHITIYNGXVXWIT
MICTIMSMOZRNZMJRMRMGZVE 
BCFUQZPFNLJEEGYWXBJBKIM
```

What is the connection between all the words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completed wordsearch is:

> [image]

There are 10 words to find in total. These are:

> RIDDLE
>  MATHEMATICS
>  LOGICALDEDUCTION
>  WORD
>  KNOWLEDGE
>  WORDPLAY
>  ENIGMATICPUZZLE
>  CIPHER
>  PATTERN
>  RHYME

These are instantly recognisable to regular users of Puzzling.SE as:

> Common question tags used on this site. And in fact, at the moment this puzzle was originally posted these were the **top 10 most used tags on Puzzling.SE** (hence the title).

Comment: Well done! That’s correct, was it hard?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Daniil :) The first word I spotted by casting my eyes around the grid was the one beginning with P, and then as a frequent user of the site I made the connection straight away and sought the others that fitted with your title, so not that hard. It would have been more difficult if some had been hidden diagonally, but even then a wordsearch is usually fairly quick to solve :) While you're here, make sure you take a look at the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) page and also explore the other puzzles this site has to offer. Most importantly, happy Puzzling!

Comment: Thanks! Try my other puzzle if you want: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98000/68905