# A crossword (+ a secret message)

Tags: cipher, crosswords

What number does this top-secret message point to?

> Ftq mzeiqd ue: ftq ecgmdq daaf ar fia tgzpdqp mzp fiqzfk ruhq

This table and crossword could help:

[image]

> **Crossword clues:**
>
> **Across:**
>
> 5. A lifeboat, perhaps
>   6. Strips in Geography class
>   9. Somewhat thin
>   10. Whirlybird
>   11. Olympic God
>   12. They come in last
>
> **Down**:
>
> 1. Kept in a gallery
>    2. Circumference measurement
>    3. Pointer
>    4. Elbows etc.
>    5. Space shuttle which launched the Hubble telescope
>    7. Permanent mark
>    8. Ball queen

Table:

```
1: A B C D E F G H I J 
2: K L M N O P Q R S T
3: U V W X Y Z
```

The first hint will be added tomorrow

Comment: Did you miss 7D clue?

Comment: @Sid yes I did, I edited the puzzle layout (clues are the same), thanks

Comment: @Sid need a hint?

Answer (score 2):

The number is

> 15

---

> Using a Caesar shift of 14 on the text, it decodes to "The answer is: the square root of two hundred and twenty five".

I'm still not sure how the crossword or table is linked.

#### Crossword solution

> [image]
>
>  1D commented by @Stiv (although not the intended solution -- see comments).
>  3D commented by @Swati.

**Next step:**

- Find how the crossword and table are used to hint to the solution.

Comment: It’s right, try and see how the crossword is linked

Comment: @Daniil I've been getting a bit stuck on a lot of these clues. I've listed a few guesses by each. Would you be able to check if I'm on the right track with any of them?

Comment: Sure: correct clues: rot13(rttorngre,nerf,qvfpbirel,gnggbb) For *they come in last* think about rot13(gur nycunorg)

Comment: @eyl327 3 can be rot13(Svatre)

Comment: Good progress, everything looks right so far, need any more clues?

Comment: @Daniil I'm not sure about the last three. Are any of my guesses right?

Comment: 1D How about rot13(FGNGHRF be fbzrguvat negl yvxr gung)?

Comment: @eyl327 Correct ones: rot13(Cnfgnf naq qbg)

Comment: I've never heard the word 13/  'fcnerfrg' before. Is it common in British English?

Comment: This is a bit of a reach, but for 1D, maybe 13/ 'oebamrf'.

Comment: rot13(fgnghrf) can work for 1D as the word I intended is quite hard and uncommon, the puzzle can still be solved with your word

Comment: Do you want a hint for the next step?

Comment: I suspect the table is involved with rot13[n pvcure fvzvyne gb npunf orgn va Uroerj (N orpbzrf X, X orpbzrf H, H orpbzrf N, O orpbzrf Y, rgp.) ]. Probably will have to select rot13(svefg be ynfg yrggref) from the crossword answers. Haven't found anything meaningful yet, though.

Comment: I'll give you a clue rot13(ebg naq Prnfne jvyy or lbhe sevraq bapr lbh pbzcyrgr guvf chmmyr)

Comment: @Daniil I've tried some more things that don't seem to be working. Is any of this going to be helpful to me? https://i.imgur.com/2zOexOT.png

Comment: @eyl327 yes it is helpful, you need to get 1 number

Comment: Any luck at finding the number?